# POST call in Mulesoft

Tags: http-post, mule-studio

I am trying to make a HTTPS POST call in mulesoft to an external API. I had read in the mulesoft documentation and also in other posts that in order to send the request body, a map has to be prepared.
Hence, i am using the "Set-Payload" to prepare a map.
Eg: #[{'key':'value'}]
When I am using the logger to display it, it prints a map (as expected).
But when the POST call is being made, i am receiving the following error:

Response code 503 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream

Payload : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@3f8f77a

Could anyone let me know where am i going wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server you're trying to call is returning status 503. Have you tried calling the external API using other client SOAP/Postman/Curl?

Also check this out:
http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/2009/consume-get-restful-service.html

Comment: Yes, I had tried calling using POSTMAN. The responses that I am receiving are alternating between error code : 400 and 503.

Comment: Thanks for the reference URL. It helped! In my case giving the 'query-paramter' instead of setting the payload helped. Also adding the status validator was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should set proper mimetype for muleMessage and set the http POST method, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

While posting the data male sure how your http is expecting the input. What ever the transformations you want to make before posting do it, finally when posting the data to http cross check your data type with the data in the server your are trying to send. Both needs to match. Then it work.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to Isolate HTTP interaction problems into two parts. One is related to request itself for e.g. URL,Method,Headers,Payload,MimeType and other should be related to transport and network interaction with Server itself. To better view the information for both of the above details use a htt[ proxy/debugger [for. e.g. Fiddler] around the traffic flowing while you make a request. This will throw more light on the stuff hindering you while making this call successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the below sugestions-:

Set payload as map, mention MIME Type as application/json and then use json to object transformer (with return class as java.util.HashMap).

Set payload as simple string. This could help.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 503 implies that the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay.
Please try resending the message or hit the API with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change the port in the request-config to 443 since you're using HTTPS.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="jiratst.murex.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="/rest/api/2/project">
```

Answer (score 0):

try using input {'key':'value'} in set payload instead of Array.